# Half pyramid formation when scrambling words (python) (Beginner)

Tags: python

```
import random


string = "This is a string"
string = list(string)
jumbled = ""
print(string)


for length in range(0, len(string)):
    jumbled += string.pop(random.randint(0, len(string) - 1))

    print(jumbled)
```

but the output is:

```
      
      3
      36
      365
      3652
      36528
      36528
      36528
      36528
      36528   7
      36528   71
      36528   71
      36528   71 0
      36528   71 0
      36528   71 0 4
      36528   71 0 49
```

I want this to be in a regular line(like this sentence), instead of this wierd triangle formation.

Thanks,
Synthx

Comment: you're just trying to scramble the letters and print them out?

Comment: Just move the `print` function call out of the loop - I don't know where you're getting the numeric digits from.  I get letters when I run your code.

Comment: What can I do about the spaces in between the letters?

Comment: You have spaces in your input string.  They're as valid as any other character when you scramble the string.  So they're still in there, just scrambled, like all the other characters.  So you explicitly want to have spaces in your input string but not in your output string?  Your question says nothing about that.

Comment: How many lines of output do you see? So, how many times did `print` run? How many lines of output do you want to see? So, how many times *should* `print` happen? How many times did the loop run? Do you see a pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest fix is to move the print statement outside the loop:

```
import random


string = "This is a string"
string = list(string)
jumbled = ""
print(string)


for length in range(0, len(string)):
    jumbled += string.pop(random.randint(0, len(string) - 1))

print(jumbled)
```

But python has more concise/efficient syntax for many common operations.  A better solution might be:

```
import random
my_string = "This is a string"

my_str_list = list(my_string)
random.shuffle(my_str_list) # does shuffling in-place, should be fast
print("".join(my_str_list)) 
# prints: sstsagThii i rn
```